# Why does it need onBackpressure() here for click events?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to make error handling for some action bound for button clicks. For binding I use RxAndroid+RxAndroid. Seems like it must work with code below, but it doesn't with commented line with `onBackpressure()`:

```
CurrentUser signIn() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
Integer x = 1;
PublishSubject<Throwable> loginingFailedSubject = PublishSubject.create();

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    RxView.clicks(loginButton)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext((v) -> setLoginingWaiting())

            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .map((v) -> signIn())
            .lift(new SuppressErrorOperator<>(throwable -> {
                Log.e("MyTag", "Oops, failed " + x.toString() + " times!");
                ++x;
                loginingFailedSubject.onNext(throwable);
            }))
            //.onBackpressureBuffer()

            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(user -> setLoginedUser(user));

    loginingFailedSubject
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(throwable -> setLoginingFailed(throwable));
}
```

And this is `SuppressErrorOperator` code:

```
public final class SuppressErrorOperator<T> implements 

Observable.Operator<T, T> {
    final Action1<Throwable> errorHandler;

    public SuppressErrorOperator(Action1<Throwable> errorHandler) {
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
    }

    public SuppressErrorOperator() {this(null);}

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
        return new Subscriber<T>(subscriber) {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                if (errorHandler != null) {
                    errorHandler.call(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(T t) {
                subscriber.onNext(t);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And this is what I got in my logcat in last after 100 clicks:
`Oops, failed 16 times!`

It stops after exaclty 16 times and on 17th, it runs through `setLoginingWaiting()` (I see it, because this method disables button that also means, nobody can click more than 1 times per request. Or near that number) and.. that's all. Seems like it doesn't get to `.lift()` at all.

But if I uncomment `.onBackpressureBuffer()`, it perfectly works now! I read a lot about backpressure. I even spend whole day to understand source code of `Observable`, `Subscriber` e.t.c.

I know, what 16 - is a constant size for Android buffer. But why is it hit? I don't click button that often. Also, there is no `onNext()` at all, so the buffer cannot exceed in any case! All `onError()` swallowed by `Operator`.

I also know `observeOn()` works via pull protocol so it internally wants to use `request()`. And if I comment last `observeOn()` before `.subscribe(user -> setLoginedUser(user));` - it will work too (but of course, it is unacceptable).

**But why and what is it that need `onBackpressure()` here for be alive? Also, why does it die without any exception like `MissingBackpressureException` or something like that?**

Comment: ok, problem was really interesting, so I dived into Rx sources. Looks like ObserveOnSubscriber sets max request count to 16. God knows why. So the queue is OK, it's empty, but the `requested` value of subscriber is hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you interfere with the lifecycle of the stream. `map` crashes but you suppress the exception and there is no value sent to downstream. If downstream doesn't get any value, it can't know it should request more, thus the whole sequence stalls, letting the buffers fill up. `onBackpressureBuffer` works only because it requests Long.MAX_VALUE and keeps the source running.

*Note, however, that `map` shouldn't really work the way it does now but unsubscribe on the first sign of error from the function.*

The correct alternative would be:

```
RxView.clicks(loginButton)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnNext((v) -> setLoginingWaiting())
.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.flatMap(v -> {
    try {
        return Observable.just(signIn());
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        Log.e("MyTag", "Oops, failed " + x.toString() + " times!");
        ++x;
        loginingFailedSubject.onNext(ex);
        return Observable.empty();
    }
 })
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(user -> setLoginedUser(user));
```

Answer (score 1):

OperatorObserveOn has a queue with a size of RxRingBuffer.SIZE (16 on android), if you exceed the size of this queue a MissingBackpressure exception will thrown.

Generally to avoid backpressure problems you can limit switching threads, limit events emission (throttle, buffer etc) or use onBackpressureXXX operators.

Though looks like in your case - login button - you only need to handle one request at a time, so why don't hide the button with ProgressBar or set enable(false) for the time of a request

Comment: As I mentioned, I knew, what `OpeartorObserverOn` has 16 size and what does this size mean. I also said about disabling button (wrote it more clearly now). It is disabled during the chain, so I can't understand, why there is backpressure problem at all.

Comment: @SemyonDanilov, but why do they stuck there? There is no time consuming onNext-handlers and all errors are suppressed by next-to-throwing operator so nobody must know about emitted error and all must work as expected without any onCompleted or onError calls

Comment: @Nexen could the problem be that you are not calling subscriber's onError in your operator? (only errorHanlder is called)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is an error is in `OperatorObserveOn::ObserveOnSubscriber`.

In init method it sets new Producer and increment `requested` (of `ObserveOnSubscriber`) by inner subscriber's (child) `requested`. But when `ObserveOnSubscriber` is the child it has a default value (in case of Android -- 16) of `Subscriber::requested` and the real value of `requested` is in `ObserveOnSubscriber::requested`.
The problem is, that `Subscriber::requested` is used and is not updated. So the fix is to rewrite init method of `ObserveOnSubscriber` (I just copied OperatorObserveOn's sources and created the copy of it in the package with same name as in RxJava).

```
    void init() {
        // don't want this code in the constructor because `this` can escape through the 
        // setProducer call
        Subscriber<? super T> localChild = child;

        localChild.setProducer(new Producer() {

            @Override
            public void request(long n) {
                if (n > 0L) {
                    BackpressureUtils.getAndAddRequest(requested, n);
                    ObserveOnSubscriber.this.request(requested.get());
                    schedule();
                }
            }

        });
        localChild.add(recursiveScheduler);
        localChild.add(this);
    }
```

I also created [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3889) on github.